# gpg-agent GENKEY via cli for simplest RSA , invalid length specifier in sexp returned, using documentation example

Tags: gnupg, s-expression, libgcrypt, gpg-agent

https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/Agent-GENKEY.html

When I execute gpg-agent --server for an interactive session, and enter the example from this site, I get the following error :

"gpg-agent[14]: failed to convert keyparam: Invalid length specifier in S-expression"

Doesn't matter if I use one or two spaces between nbits and len. Doesn't matter if I change the value to other usual RSA sizes. I also don't copy paste but enter into terminal manually. Also tried on multiple systems. System provided on RH8, custom build of everything gpg related out of master branches from github, and system ones from Debial-WSL. I've also ran a debug session (on the master branch) and one of the libgcrypt scanning functions that actually parse the string into sexp returns an error. The input string is ok, it is what I entered, properly terminated.

Although debugging through that parser is doable I wanted to ask here first in case I'm doing something wrong.